# Adding interface to get request

Tags: angular

I am trying to add an interface to my code but am stuck with where and how to put it. Please see my code below.

Service.ts

```
getData() {
  return this.httpClient.get(Constants.API_ENDPOINT + 'data.json');
}
```

Component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.apiService.getData().subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

Interface.ts

```
export interface Items {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  url: string;
}
```

How would I change the service.ts to use the interface?

Comment: As a side note `Items` would not be a great name of that structure. It is not descriptive (an Item as a noun is very generic) and it also indicates there are multiple instances. I would keep it singular and think of a more descriptive name for the interface type. This might just be an abstraction of your actual code and maybe you are already doing this in which case feel free to ignore this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Define the return type on `getData`
- Use the generic overload of [`HttpClient.get<T>`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) to define the structure of the data being returned.

```
getData() : Observable<Items> {
   return this.httpClient.get<Items>(Constants.API_ENDPOINT + 'data.json');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare return type of Items type in your service:-

```
  getData(): Observable<Items>{
     return this.httpClient.get<Items>(Constants.API_ENDPOINT + 'data.json');
  }
```

And in your component you can do this:-

```
  ngOnInit() {
  this.apiService.getData().subscribe((res: Items) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

For more info see the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response)